# C# Build Chart Animate

Tags: c#, charts

I'm attempting use the C# `Chart` object to build a chart of data points. For each data point in an array, I would like to plot the point on the chart and have the bars "grow" as the points are added. So when I generate 1000 random numbers, I want to set 1,000 points on the chart all starting at zero with their values increasing by one each time. In attempting to do this, I have noticed that the chart just builds all at one time instead of adding each point and "growing" the bars. Any suggestion on how to make the bars animate? I know the chart is an image, so I don't mind if it is redrawn each time, but I can't even quite figure out a way to do that.

Here is an example of my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRolls; i++)
{
    int number = randomNumber();
    myNumberDictionary[number] += 1;

    foreach (var point in MyChart.Series["MySeries"].Points)
    {
        point.SetValueXY(Convert.ToInt32(point.XValue), myNumberDictionary[Convert.ToInt32(point.XValue)]);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `For each data point added to the chart, I would like to add the point to the chart` - that sentence makes no sense.

Comment: Cannot edit: every iteration you're taking random element of `myNumberArray` (whatever it does) and increase its value by 1. Then in internal foreach loop your setting every point's `Y` position to the proper `rolls` list element. What do those do?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. Essentially I want to plot the points each time and render a new chart every time a point is plotted.

Comment: But whad does your code mean? `point.SetValueXY` is pointless, because in every iteration of `for` loop it does exactly the same. And `myNumberDictionary[number] += 1` increases by 1 some RANDOM `myNumberDictionary` element. What are those 2 collections holding?

Comment: Yes. I was attempting to redraw the chart each time using the `point.SetValueXY`, but that didn't seem to work. `myNumberDictionary` contains a key value pair of keys `0, 1, 2` which are randomly chosen to be increased by one. Once it is increased I am attempting to redraw the chart.

Comment: Did you try using `Refresh()` method of a `Chart` object? However in winforms bitmap-based animation are never a good idea.

Comment: Refresh() is the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your task on the UI thread the drawing will wait until your task finishes. To refresh your chart (UI) when adding a new point, you to need to do it in a separate thread.

Here is an example of how to achieve it.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRolls; i++)
{
    int number = randomNumber();
    myNumberDictionary[number] += 1;

    foreach (var point in MyChart.Series["MySeries"].Points)
    {
            var startNew = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {
                 Invoke(new Action(() =>
                   point.SetValueXY(Convert.ToInt32(point.XValue),
                   myNumberDictionary[Convert.ToInt32(point.XValue)]);
             });
    }
}
```